# How to create folder and cd into it with one command

Tags: linux, shell, command

I'm looking for a command that would create a directory and bring me to it directly after, similar to:

```
$ mkdir project-one-business-dev-2
$ cd project-one-business-dev-2
```

I don't want to type the project's name twice because it's too long (I know I can use tab, but what if there are similar names?). Maybe only one command can do it.

Comment: No, there is no such a mkdir+cd command. You can use `cd !:1` to repeat the first argument of the previous command though. Or you could define a variable `myspace=project-one-bussiness-dev-2` and then `mkdir $myspace` and `cd $myspace`.

Answer (score 9):

You can do it like this:

```
mkdir project-one-business-dev-2 && cd "$_"
```

for more information check out [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/249314/how-can-i-create-a-directory-and-change-my-working-directory-to-the-new-director) on AskUbuntu

Answer (score 7):

A process can't change the working directory of it's parent process. That makes it *impossible* for an external command like `mkdir` to set the working directory of the calling shell to the newly created folder.

But you can create a bash function for that purpose. Put this for example into your `.bashrc`:

```
mkcd() {
    mkdir -p "${1}"
    cd "${1}"
}
```